# What does Sam Lombardo mean by "Never let the sun go down on an argument"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, wild-things

In the threesome scene in *Wild Things* (1998), Sam Lombardo says these words:

> Never let the sun go down on an argument.

What does he mean by this expression?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user asks to explain a particular phrase; this should be asked @ http://english.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: They seem to be asking this in the context of the scene, though. And the phrase isn't *extremely* well known (though maybe it's just me).

Comment: @BCdotWEB I don't think so, he is asking for the phrase in for understanding the show and seems fine to me.

Comment: Is this title better, in that respect?

Comment: If you don;t know what the phrase means, then you might think it's particular to this film, and should be here, rather than in an general English forum.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He's basically telling them to kiss and make up after their fight, which of course takes on another meaning in this context. It's an old saying, usually applying to couples, that recommends they settle their arguments *before* going to bed rather than letting the animosity fester overnight.

It actually originated from the bible:

> **Do not let the sun go down while you are still angry,** and do not give the devil a foothold. *[Ephesians 4:26-27]*

Comment: “It actually originated from the bible”  It certainly goes back *at least* to the bible, but it doesn’t necessarily originate there — the bible includes plenty of phrases that were established proverbs already in their time.

Comment: If you can find an even earlier instance, I'll be happy to change that. ;)

Comment: Linguist Martin H Manser wrote a book on 1700 proverbs spanning several cultures, regions, religions and numerous sources.  He gives source of this proverb as the book of Ephesians in the Bible. https://books.google.com/books?id=fgaUQc8NbTYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false